# Using regex to get string from URL?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Regex is my bete noire, can anyone help me isolate a string from a URL?

I want to get the page name from a URL which could appear in any of the following ways from an input form:

```
https://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME?sk=wall&filter=2
http://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME?sk=wall&filter=2
www.facebook.com/PAGENAME
facebook.com/PAGENAME?sk=wall
```

... and so on.

I  can't seem to find a way to isolate the string after `.com/` but before `?` (if present at all). Is it preg_match, replace or split?

If anyone can recommend a particularly clear and introductory regex guide they found useful, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [parse_url](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function and then get the last segment from the path of the url:

```
$parts=parse_url($url);
$path_parts=explode("/", $parts["path"]);
$page=$path_parts[count($path_parts)-1];
```

Comment: Typical. You don't know a PHP function exists until you needed it an hour before.

Comment: Will be better to use in-built parameters as I wrote below.

Comment: @RReverser Your solution works only if the path is "/pagename", but if it's "/path/to/pagename" it will return the wrong result

Comment: Don't agree. `substr(parse_url('https://www.facebook.com/path/to/pagename?sk=wall&filter=2', PHP_URL_PATH), 1)` returns `path/to/pagename` as is expected. As I understood, author needs all the pathname and not only last part.

Answer (score 2):

For learning and testing regexes I found RegExr, an online tool, very useful: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

But as others mentioned, parsing the url with appropriate functions might be better in this case.

Comment: Would have been a great comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this [php function (parse_url)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) directly instead of using regex.

Comment: Damn, beat me to it by 20 seconds! Good going :)

Answer (score 0):

Use smth like:

```php
substr(parse_url('https://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME?sk=wall&filter=2', PHP_URL_PATH), 1);
```